# Get toolbar in Xamarin.Forms if the first page is not a navigation page

Tags: xamarin.forms

I tried to intercept the software back button in Android. I follow several samples that  adds these:`

```
protected override void OnPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    var toolBar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
    SetSupportActionBar(toolBar);
    base.OnPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

protected override void OnResume()
{
    Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = this.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null)
        SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    base.OnResume();
}
```

Then use the `OnOptionItemSelected` to get the software back button event.

But this didn't work because, for me the first page of the app is login page that does not belong to NavigationPage. After the successful login, I change the Application.Current.MainPage to the root application page that is a NavigationPage. But it is too late, the OnPostCreate or OnResume already been called and the FindViewById(Resource.Id.toolbar) return null.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you currently working with xamarin forms ?

Comment: Yes, I actually get the "hardware" back button functionning ok, but I can't intercep the soft one.

Comment: Is this Xamarin.forms? Or xamarin.android?

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand whether you are asking xamarin.forms or xamarin.android.
For xamarin.forms

You can navigate from Login Page to Mainpage like this

```
Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new MainPage(), this);
 Navigation.PopAsync();
```

And In your App.xaml.cs

```
 MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Login());
```